# confusing by scala replaceFirst

Tags: scala

```
scala > val a = (x:Int)=>x+1
  res0: Int => Int = <function1>
scala > val b = a.getClass
  b: Class[_ <: Int => Int] = class $anonfun$1
scala > b.getName.replaceFirst("^.*\\.", "") + ".class"
  //Why there is a prefix '$read$'
  res2: String = $read$$anonfun$1.class
```

I'm confusing about the res2. I think the res2 should be '$anonfun$1.class'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This one was fun.

```
scala> val a = ((x: Int) => x).getClass.getName
a: String = $anonfun$1

scala> a == "$anonfun$1"
res2: Boolean = false
```

Wait, what?

```
scala> a.getBytes.map(_.toChar)
res3: Array[Char] = Array($, l, i, n, e, 4, ., $, r, e, a, d, $, $, i, w, $, $, i, w, $, $, a, n, o, n, f, u, n, $, 1)
```

So the name of the class is actually `$line4.$read$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$1`, not `$anonfun$1`. But why does Scala REPL print it like this? All executable Scala code must be inside a class, trait, or object definition. So when you enter a line in REPL which isn't, it gets wrapped inside an `object`. And apparently when printing an answer, REPL suppresses anything which looks like part of this object's generated name, even if it isn't where it comes from:

```
scala> "a$$iw$$b"
res7: String = a$$b
```

And `$line4.$read$` qualifies for this suppression, but `$read$` by itself doesn't.